# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private

Tags: c++

The project runs correctly under VC6.0, however, after I updated it under VS2012, the following link errors occur:

```
revel.lib(BaseEncoder.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
    "__declspec(dllimport) private: void __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::_Eos(unsigned int)" 
    (__imp_?_Eos@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAEXI@Z) referenced in function 
    "protected: virtual void __thiscall Revel_BaseEncoder::Reset(void)" (?Reset@Revel_BaseEncoder@@MAEXXZ)
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you put your code up so I can recreate the problem on my machine? Just off the top of my head have you checked your header/libs?

Comment: I think you need to rebuild `revel.lib` using VS 2012.

Comment: I've had the same issue some time ago, just go to project properties->general and there should be a platform toolset option there, change that to match the old visual studio toolset if rebuilding as Michael recommended is not an option

Comment: @MichaelBurr How to rebuild revel.lib?

Comment: @RaduChivu I checked the toolset option, there is only one option for me, which is Visual Studio 2012 (v110). How can I get the old version?

Comment: @user1964417: I don't know how to rebuild `revel.lib` - I don't know what it is.  The error message indicates that `revel.lib` wants something from the `std:string` class implementation, and MSVC's C++ runtime library is not backwards/forwards compatible in general.  The `std::string::_Eos()` implementation-detail function was last included in the C++ runtime as an exported function in VS 2008. The `revel` library apparently needs to be built against the C++ library implementation that's in VS 2012.

Comment: @MichaelBurr my guess is that the revel lib was given to him in a binary format, rather than source, so rebuilding might not be a solution for him

Comment: @RaduChivu: that may mean he's stuck with VC6. However, if `revel.lib` is the "Really Easy Video Encoding Library" (http://revel.sourceforge.net/) then source is available. Doesn't mean that rebuilding will be a snap, but it should be possible.

Comment: @MichaelBurr sorry, wasn't aware of that, yeah it's probably better that way too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely it's because you're using a library built with dependencies for an older version of stl than what you currently have.
You can set the compiler to use the old toolchain from the project properties so you can still use VS 2012 and get it to compile provided that you still have the old visual studio installed.

EDIT:To change the platform toolset, go to Project Properties->General, there should be an option called Platform Toolset there with a dropdown that you can use to select the older version of the toolchain as per the online msdn documentation ([link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff770576.aspx))

I am unsure if VS 6.0 will appear in said dropdown, but if it doesn't, you can find a method to change it yourself [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcprerelease/thread/226f7b5a-f777-43c1-b73b-e9c017471cab)

Comment: How can I use the old version compiler?

Comment: You might be able to create your own 'Platform Toolset' configuration for building with VC6 inside VS 2012. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx in addition to the link in Radu's answer.  A possibly simpler solution might be to just use a makefile project in VS 2012 that uses the VC6 tools - VC6 will even helpfully generate a makefile for you from the VC6 project (a feature that MS removed from all newer versions of VC++).

Comment: So bad solution, if I only have installed 2013 ? or 2015 .. please, I don't need install versions old 2012/11/10/09....1990 to work a program .

Comment: You only need to do this if you don't have the source code, only a library that was compiled with an older version of STL. If you do have a library that is built against the old version and you specifically require to use that library, then unfortunately you have to install the version of VS that was used to build it so you have the same toolchain

Comment: I'm using  programs last generation C ++, I'm not going to put a project at risk just by having to down a version.I'll find another method